# How does the genie's mana collection work

Tags: dungeon-defenders

There is a mana collection rating, but what does this rating do, how does it translate to how much mana is returned per hit?

Comment: Higher mana collection rating = more mana collected per hit. That seems obvious, so I guess you're looking for the numbers? I'll look out for a genie so I can test this.

Comment: @Arkive, well I tried it with my squire who's using an elemental weapon and the mana collected was negligible (4 mana for a 6000 damage hit), so there's more than just higher rating = more mana involved.  Perhaps the enemy you hit also matters.

Comment: My guess is your own damage doesn't matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://forums.trendyent.com/showthread.php?32590-Some-Math-on-Genies

Here's the exact math on genies for DD. The post comes to the following conclusions:

> Genies scale exceedingly poorly and a perfect genie will not pass 350 mana returned.
>
> 5,000 damage per swing/shot is more than enough to cap the mana return from a genie, as the base damage goes up, the damage requirement to cap the mana goes down.

Comment: Hi Reikou, can you please post the information from the forums into your answer so its easier for others to see it in case the forum goes down?

Comment: @yx To be fair, given the large amount of information + graphs present in the post I don't think it's realistic to copy all of the content to here. Still, I edited in the conclusion that the post comes to.

Comment: I think we can trust Mana on this. It seems right up his ally.